# How to force a windows service created using install4j to run as soon as machine wake-up from sleep mode

Tags: install4j

I am looking for an option/configuration or any other settings to force a windows/mac service that’s created using install4j to trigger automatically after the machine wake up from sleep mode
Right now OS (at least based on my testing and the scheduled frequency) doing this job after some x minutes. Now I am looking for a way to trigger my service to start as soon as machine wake up from sleep.
If there are no settings/support from install4j we might need to look into an option to do this through programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

As of 7.0, install4j has no functionality to perform actions on wakeup.

A discussion of this problem is found at

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27036/possible-to-run-scripts-on-sleep-and-wake

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Ingo.